# How to send parameters to BCP inside dynamic sql using sp_executesql

Tags: sql-server, dynamic-sql, bcp

We are trying to run a BCP-query dynamically to put some data to files. However, when using the following code, it does not seem that sp_executesql understands that @RId inside the BCP query is a parameter. Is there any way to send that parameter value all the way in? When running this, the error message is:
Error = [Microsoft][SQL Server Native Client 10.0][SQL Server]Must declare the scalar variable "@RId".

Query:

```
DECLARE @REPORTID Nvarchar(500) = 'SomeID_Resend2019-02-20 11:38:24.040';
DECLARE @Path varchar(500) = '\\server\folder\_FileName.csv';

DECLARE @SQL nvarchar(500);

SET @SQL
    = N'master.dbo.xp_cmdshell ''BCP "SELECT RowValues FROM ServerName.dbo.TableName WHERE ReportId = @RId" queryout @Path -t, -T -N -S SERVERNAME\INSTANCENAME''';

EXEC sp_executesql @SQL,
                   N'@RId nVARCHAR(500), @Path VARCHAR(500)',
                   @REPORTID,
                   @Path;
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you'll have to *externalize* those parameters when generating the dynamic SQL.  Something like:

```
DECLARE @REPORTID Nvarchar(500) = 'SomeID_Resend2019-02-20 11:38:24.040';
DECLARE @Path varchar(500) = '\\server\folder\_FileName.csv';

DECLARE @SQL nvarchar(500);

SET @SQL
    = N'master.dbo.xp_cmdshell ''BCP "SELECT RowValues FROM ServerName.dbo.TableName WHERE ReportId = ''''' + @REPORTID + '" queryout ' + @Path + ' -t, -T -N -S SERVERNAME\INSTANCENAME''';
PRINT @SQL
--EXEC sp_executesql @SQL
```

---

The `PRINT` statement reveals the generated dynamic SQL

```
master.dbo.xp_cmdshell 'BCP "SELECT RowValues FROM ServerName.dbo.TableName WHERE ReportId = ''SomeID_Resend2019-02-20 11:38:24.040" queryout \\server\folder\_FileName.csv -t, -T -N -S SERVERNAME\INSTANCENAME'
```

Comment: But won't that negate the purpose of parameterization in sp_executesql? We wanted to use that to protect against injection. With your example I think it will be vulnerable to sql injection?

Comment: @GHauan - I think you'll have to validate your input parameters (outside of the sp_executesql) before building the dynamic SQL to execute the BCP command.  I'm not sure how susceptible BCP would be to SQL injection (especially the Queryout), but you could certainly code up a _before_ sp_executesql with parameters to select for a valid reportid.